# Session invalidates after Tomcat restart

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I keep my session alive when restarting Tomcat? It falls every time, but it's not what I'm actually expecting. I'm making a site and I'm not comfortable on entering data to get main page every time after reloading server... Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834330/how-do-you-persist-a-tomcat-session

Comment: What did you save in the session? How do you restart your server? What technics are you using for mvc?

Comment: I save there regular objects. I'm restarting my server pressing button "Restart" on Tomcat v6.0. I'm using Eclipse Indigo (latest release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all attributes serializable?  See:
 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had no idea that attributes have to implement Serializable. Now all is working, thank you :)